# pytest. execute all teardown modules

Tags: python, pytest

i have use funcargs in my tests:

`def test_name(fooarg1, fooarg2):`

all of them have pytest_funcarg__ factories, which returns request.cached_setup, so all of them have setup/teardown sections.

sometimes i have a problem with fooarg2 teardown, so i raise exception in here. in this case ignore all the others teardowns(fooarg1.teardown, teardown_module, etc) and just goes to pytest_sessionfinished section.

is there any option in pytest not to collect exceptions and execute all remaining teardowns functions?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using pytest-2.5.1?  pytest-2.5 and in particular issue287 is supposed to have brought support for running all finalizers and re-raising the first failed exception if any.

Comment: If this answer does indeed answer your question, perhaps you can accept it by clicking the green check mark? Not least of all it will gain you some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

In your teardown function you can catch the error and print it.

```
def teardown(): # this is the teardown function with the error
    try:
        # the original code with error
    except:
        import traceback 
        traceback.print_exc() # no error should pass silently
```